# How can I install the developmental version of `data.table 1.9.3` on Rstudio mounted on a redhat linux server?

Tags: linux, r, data.table

I am currently trying to use the foverlaps function in the data.table 1.9.3 version. However, I need a lot of RAM and power. Hence, I am paying by the hour to use the Revolution R Linux software on Amazon, which is mounted onto an EC2 122 GB RAM server.

The problem I am having is that in order to run data.table version 1.9.3, I must use the function `install_github`. However, I cannot install `devtools` in R. I looked around here on stackoverflow and realized that the `curl-dev` package must be installed. However, Revolution R doesn't allow me to use sudo commands. Therefore, I cannot install the newest version of data.table 1.9.3.

I am currently not sure what I can do. I have also tried to directly copy the newest zip version of 1.9.3 into the library, and R does recognize I just installed version 1.9.3, but I am unable to call out any functions. For example, when I do: `?foverlaps`, I just get  "No documentation for ‘foverlaps’ in specified packages and libraries.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get 1.9.3 up and running on an linux redhat server Rstudio mount? Thanks!

Comment: I am using RevoR on a centOS machine hosted on EC2.  I use devtools and data.table regularly. Try `sudo RevoR` then installing your packages (thought that shouldnt be necessary).  You can sudo install dependencies outside of R if needed.

Comment: How did you install the package from the ZIP file? I have tried that approach and works for me (see my answer).

Comment: After rereading your post I realized you said you copied the ZIP version of the package to the library (I guess you mean the library directory in the R install location). That won't work. You have to install it via `R CMD INSTALL <dir>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the **Download ZIP** button in the right side of the [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) page, unzip it and run `R CMD INSTALL <unzipped directory>` from a terminal. The only problem with this approach is that it will not automatically install dependencies, and the installation will fail until you do so. Looking at the *Imports* field it seems you need to install packages *chron* and *reshape2*. You may install those (if not already installed) with install.packages().

Comment: If this works, please give the answer a tick :) A note: data.table_1.9.4 is out on cran.

Comment: You mean me? But I am the answerer- can't give me self tick! :)

Comment: @user1398057: see if you could download directly from cran.  It's version 1.9.4 on cran.  Development version is bumped upto 1.9.5.